# Adding white space to a shutter screen shot

Tags: screenshot, image-processing, shutter

I have a taken a screenshot with [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), and I wish to annotate the screenshot, so I click on edit. How do I add white space around the screenshot to put my annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have clicked on edit, in the edit window you see small square handles around the picture. Drag these handles to create a canvas around the picture. You can also drag the picture within the canvas to position it. Right click on the canvas to choose the background color. After that you can annotate your screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible, not easily at least**

The inbuilt editor in shutter is meant to be easy and simple, not full featured one.So it misses out many features that other image editors like `GIMP` have.

You can still get a white space around the image, but that would include a lot of painstaking steps, like **enlarging the background, cutting the image, adding a white rectangle and again pasting the image**.

The simpler solution would be to change shutter settings, so that it would open the image in your favorite image editor.Then you may edit the image there.

---

**HOW TO CHANGE DEFAULT EDITOR**

1. Go to *Edit->Preferences*
2. In actions tab, select open with
   [image]
3. Select your favorite image editor here.
4. Close.

Comment: hmm, this sounds like a novel way to do this. Unfortunately I don't know how to use gimp to add white space either :p

Comment: @Alex Even I don't know how to add white space using GIMP, but maybe some other editor may help.There are many in USC.